# Is Shopify metafield ID unique only for single user or it's unique at all?

Tags: database, shopify

Question is: can I set 'shopify_id' column (that will be contain metafield ID) unique in my app database or IDs may repeat for different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metafield IDs are guaranteed to be unique across all shops.